# Finding the value of y in terms of x.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

Is it possible to get the value of $y$ in terms of $x$ from the below equation? If so please give give me a clue how to do that :)
$$y \sqrt{y^2 + 1} + \ln\left(y + \sqrt{y^2 + 1}\right) = \frac{a}{x^2}.$$

Comment: Please verify that the LaTeX I entered gives your intended equation.

Comment: Here is the link to the equation in the higher quality http://postimage.org/image/99zftkfaj/

Comment: Yes it is correct, thank you very much :)

Comment: Should the equation start $y\sqrt{y^2+1}$ or $y + \sqrt{y^2+1}$? If the answer is the latter then there is a very simple solution. If the answer is the former then the solution is very messy, involving solutions to quadric equations.

Comment: Unfortunately, it is a multiplication. Can you tell me please how to start with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $\ \rm{asinh}(y)=\ln\left(y + \sqrt{y^2 + 1}\right)\ $ let's set $\ y:=\sinh(u)\ $ and rewrite your equation as :

$$\sinh(u) \sqrt{\sinh(u)^2 + 1} + u = \frac{a}{x^2}$$
$$\sinh(u) \cosh(u) + u = \frac{a}{x^2}$$
$$\sinh(2u) + 2u = 2\frac{a}{x^2}$$

After that I fear you'll have to solve this numerically (to get $u$ in function of $x$).

I don't see something simpler sorry...

---

To solve $\ \sinh(w) + w = r\ $ numerically you may :

- use iterations (Newton-Raphson) : $\ \displaystyle w_{n+1}=w_n-\frac  {\sinh(w_n)+w_n-r}{\cosh(w_n)+1}$
  (starting with $w_0=\frac r2$)
- use reversion of series to get $w=w(r)$ :
  $w(r)= \frac 12 r - \frac 1{96}r^3 + \frac 1{1920}r^5 - \frac{43}{1290240}r^7 + \frac {223}{92897280}r^9 - \frac{60623}{326998425600}r^{11} + \frac{764783}{51011754393600}r^{13} - \frac {107351407}{85699747381248000}r^{15} + \mathrm{O}\bigl(r^{17}\bigr)$
- perhaps that other methods exist in the litterature...

Comment: I have started with it and i thought that there will be a way to avaid a numerical solution if I try to do something with these logarithms. I was trying to solve it for 2 hours and nothing so probably you are right and it is simply not possible to do.

Comment: @user1354439: the problem is that you have a $\ln$ in the second term and none in the first : these two terms are of different type ! I'll add some numerical methods in my answer,

Comment: No really thanks i was trying to determine the path eqation of the ball thrown with taking drag force ( proportional to the square of the velocity) into account. This equation according to my knowladge does not yet exist despite many attempts to find it. I was stupid that i thought i can do it :)

Comment: @user1354439: too late done! :-) (and with fast convergence)

Comment: My reputation is 1 :D i cant give you 1 up :(

Comment: @user1354439: Thanks anyway and fine continuation !

Comment: Thank you so much for your time. Just wait me to get 15 points haha

Comment: @user1354439: +1 to begin your generous work (not for me, I don't really need it!).